# Update Status in a publication list

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there an easy way to update a status in a publication list as the status is unsubscribed and I'm trying to find a way to bulk update them to Active.

I have tried importing a csv file with the status as active but this doesn't update the status

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no one step way of doing this, but this should work for you.

**1. Create Staging Table**

Create a data extension to hold records of Unsubscribed subscriber records you are going to get with a Query Activity. The fields should look something like the following:

[image]

**2. Query Activity**

Create a query activity to get unsubscribed records from your Publication List changing the ListID below for the ID of your Publication List of interest:

```
SELECT
    SubscriberKey AS [Subscriber Key],
    EmailAddress AS [Email Address],
    'Active' AS Status
FROM
    _ListSubscribers WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    Status = 'Unsubscribed' AND
    ListID = 495
```

**3. Data Extract**
Create a Data Extract Activity in the Activities tab of Automation Studio. The type of extract you need is a Data Extension Extract. Raise a case with Support, if this is not available within your account.

**4. File Transfer**
Create a File Transfer Activity in the Activities tab of Automation Studio. Have this "Upload" the file with the name you stipulated in Step 3 to the "ExactTarget Enhanced FTP" File Location.

**5. Import Definition**
Create an Import Definition in the Activities tab of Automation Studio to Import the file with the name you stipulated in Step 3 from the ExactTarget Enhanced FTP. The target of the import will be your Publication List, the Mapping would by "By Header Row" and the Data Action in this instance would be either "Update Only" or "Add and Update"

**6. Automation**
Create a new Automation in Automation Studio. Add the items created in 2, 3, 4 and 5. Save and run the Automation.

Comment: I've tried creating a CSV file with a status of Active but it didn't change the status in the publication list when I used an import activity for the unsubscribe records

Comment: Could you take a look at the errors file on the FTP, please? Are there any rejections of individual records in the file? Taking a look at one of the subscribers in all subs, are they also unsubbed n all subscribers?