# How can I import or create a query that unsubscribes old users from a migrated email system?

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscriber

Just got onboarded and taking over our email program. We migrated from Hubspot approx 6 months ago and have not sent many emails to that audience since. When migrating to SFMC, instead of inserting those contacts as unsubscribed, they were inserted from our Saleforce lead side and they have a subscribed subscription status. There is a DE that contains those contacts that were unsubscribed from the old system, but ideally they should simply marked as unsubscribed in SFMC so they can resubscribe in the future if so desired (rather than suppressed for as long as possible).

Is there a way to either import subscription details into All Subscribers or create a query that updates All Subscribers based on that Data Extension?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way we have found is to do it through the API - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm

There was also a [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/177949/47266) posted about going from unsub to active with the use of an automation that was answered.  You could follow their instructions to go the other way around as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an automation:

1. Write the contents of the DE to FTP with a Data Extract activity
2. Import the contacts from the FTP file into the All Subscribers list - it seems this is currently the only possible way to change the subscriber status in All Subscribers automatically.